# Is it possible to use TextRenderingHint to get anti-aliasing on a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, antialiasing

I've been experimenting with enabling anti-aliasing of text in various controls in a Windows Forms Application.

I did a bit of research and it seems like the solution is to create a custom control and to override `OnPaint()` to modify the `TextRenderingHint`. I have used this approach successfully on `Label` and `Button` controls, but it appears not to work for `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` controls.

Here is the code I am using to enable anti-aliasing in a custom `Label` control:

```
public partial class CustomLabel : Label
{
    private System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint _hint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    public System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint TextRenderingHint
    {
        get { return this._hint; }
        set { this._hint = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint;
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Using the same approach for a `TextBox` or a `RichTextBox` does not appear to work.

The application I'm creating deals primarily with text input and I would really like to use anti-aliasing for all of the displayed text, especially text being typed into a TextBox or RichTextBox or a custom control.

Comment: Why not just enable ClearText on Windows?

Comment: Don't they anti-alias to some degree by default?

Comment: I have cleartype enabled but using TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit makes text look significantly better

Comment: So I've just now discovered WPF and I'm very happy to find that text is anti-aliased in all of the controls I have tried so far. So it looks like I'll be re-building my app in WPF :)